# How do you dispose of an IDisposable in Managed C++?

Tags: .net, idisposable, managed-c++

I'm trying to Dispose of an IDisposable object(FileStream^ fs) in managed C++ (.NET 2.0) and am getting the error

> Dispose' : is not a member of 'System::IO::FileStream

It says that I should invoke the destructor instead. Will calling

```
fs->~FileStream();
```

call the dispose method on the FileStream object? Why can't I call Dispose?

Comment: I had this problem too, thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The correct pattern is to just delete the object:

```
delete fs;
```

This will be translated into a call to Dispose().

See [this post](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/08/22/managed-c-destructor/) for some of the details of what is going on under the hood. The advantage of this idiom is that it allows you to write:

```
{
  FileStream fs(...)
  ...
}
```

And have the Dispose method called correctly ... equivalent to a using block in C#. The file stream object is still allocated on the managed heap.

Comment: Even better is the ways this automatically chains through members defined with stack style semantics.

Comment: Forgot this and used this answer again. I wish I could accept/vote up twice!